# How do I access the startup processes if there is no Cinnamon desktop shown?

Tags: compiz, cinnamon, emerald

I just recently switched my system over to Ubuntu 12.10, and decided on Cinnamon as my environment-- it all worked fine, at first. But I was poorly educated and started using Compiz and Emerald along with it--Setting both as replacements in startup processes.
I now know, that's a big, big mistake. 
Now when loading Cinnamon, I am greeted to my background image, and only that. My only options seem to be to open a terminal.

I was advised to attempt

> muffin --replace

and

> mutter --replace

Neither to any avail, the terminal closes, and I cannot load another one unless I completely reload.

I went back to Unity, purged and autoremoved Cinnamon, emerald, and compizconfig, and attempted to reinstall Cinnamon, thinking that would solve the problem--no, it came back just as broken as before.

So, I reinstalled ubuntu, then cinnamon---still broken.

I'm assuming I must find a way to remove the replace commands-- but as I have no menu, I'm not positive I can do that.

Is there any way I can access the startup processes via terminal? 
I'd think though, if I completely removed Cinnamon, all configurations would be gone too, so, it's just not making much sense. 
Is there some kind of reset I could possibly do?
I've been browsing forums and questions here, all leading to things I'd already done, so, it can't hurt to ask for myself. 
I apologize if you would rather I have posted this over at mint.

Next time, I will definitely check compatibility instead of assuming something just has to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Cinnamon uses muffin, but Unity uses mutter.

Answer (score 2):

Access the settings and startup processes for Cinnamon via Unity, and, after quickly removing aforementioned processes.

> It seems although it didn't allow me to do it before, I was now allowed to access the settings and startup processes for Cinnamon via Unity, and, after quickly removing aforementioned processes- I'm up and running again.

Source: an edit to the author's question.

Answer (score 0):

When you at the stage where you can see your background and nothing else, you use the keyboard shortcut, Ctrl+Alt+T, to open a terminal.

If you can't access a terminal that way, you could access one of the tty terminals by holding down the keys Ctrl, Alt, and F1 (F1-6 will work). Next, attempt to login. When you're logged-in, you're free to execute commands in that terminal.

When you have a terminal open and ready to use, enter in `export DISPLAY=:0.0` so that commands executed can use your graphical display.

Next enter in `cinnamon-session-properties` to open the Startup Applications Preferences on display 0.0.

If you're in a tty terminal and want to go back to your regular display (0.0), hold down Ctrl, Alt, and F8.